# Kaspersky 6.0 Workstations with windows 7 doesn't work

Tags: anti-virus, kaspersky

I have a Kaspersky Anti-Virus 6.0 for Windows Workstations v. 6.0.3.x, and the license is for 10 PCs. I installed it on Windows XP based machines and all of them work fine. Got only one PC with Windows 7. I receive an error message on that PC: Protection components failed to start.

Comment: 6.0 is really old. Why would you use it? It won't even protect you. Get a new crack ( I doubt its a legal key ) or install Avast Free!.

Comment: i bought the license from a computer shop for 320$
he install the program for me and did everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to version **6.0.4.1424**.

I use it at work under Windows 7 x64 with no issues so far.

Have a look here:

http://support.kaspersky.com/wks6mp4?level=2

It is officially compatible with Windows 7.

Comment: thanks alot
i think it will work with me but do you know if i can use the same license with it or i have to bought new one?

Comment: You can probably use your version 6 10 PC license as long as you install it on at most 10 PCs.

Answer (score 1):

Kaspersky Anti-Virus 6.0 isn't compatible with Windows 7 - you need to upgrade Kaspersky

Comment: thanks
but the upgrade is for free or what?
becouse i already paid for the license

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the program.
It might caused by some faulty update.